# Unramified étale cohomology groups & unramified Milnor-Witt K-groups: any relation to notion of unramifiedness in number theory

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

Let $X$ be an integral locally noetherian smooth
scheme over base field $k$. Then for every point $x \in X^{(1)}$ of codimension $1$, the stalk $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$  is a discrete valuation
ring. Choose some uniformizer $\pi_x \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$. Then we get a *residue homomorphism*

$$ \partial_{MW}^{\pi_x}: \text{K}_n^{MW}(F(X)) \to \text{K}_{n-1}^{MW}(F(x)), \ (\{\pi_x, u_2, ... , u_n \}) \mapsto (\{ \overline{u_2}, ... , \overline{u_n} \})  $$

where here $F(X)$ is the function field of $X$, $k(x)= \mathcal{O}_{X,x}/m_x$  the residue fieeld of $x$, $u_i \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x}^{\times} $
units and $\overline{u_i}$ their residues with respect residue map
$v_x: \mathcal{O}_{X,x} \to k(x)$. (the terminology can be looked up  eg in F. Morel's $\mathbb{A}^1$-Algebraic Topology over a Field).

The *$n$-th unramified Milnor-Witt K-group* of $X$ is defined as

$$ \text{K}^{MW}_{n, unr}(X) := \text{Ker}(\sum_{x \in  X^{(1)}} \partial_{MW}^{\pi_x})   $$

where

$$\sum_{x \in  X^{(1)}} \partial_{MW}^{\pi_x}: \text{K}_n^{MW}(F(X)) \to
\bigoplus_{x \in  X^{(1)}} \text{K}_{n-1}^{MW}(F(x))  $$

**Question:** Is there a natural reason to call these groups "unramified" and is there any relation known to the concept of "unramifiedness" in context of splitting behavoir of prime ideals in number fields in [algebraic number theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_of_prime_ideals_in_Galois_extensions#Definitions), justifying this name? Or are these two notions completely unrelated, but then the question is where this notion else come from; surely it not falls from heaven.

A naive guess of mine where the notion might come from: There exist so called *Gersten complex for Milnor K-theory* which is structurally similar to Gersten complex for étale cohomology, which involve so called unramified étale cohomology groups
$H^i_{ur}(X, \mu_2^{\otimes i})$. If that's the origin of the name
of "unramified" for unramified Milnor-Witt K-groups, the question turn's into what is the origin of the the name "unramified" for unramified étale cohomology groups.

Rmk.: The identical question was already [posted in MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435127/in-which-sense-unramified-milnor-witt-k-groups-are-unramified), but I think that maybe that's a more appropriate plattform for it.